# Is it still an observer pattern without the interfaces for observer and subject? Here is an example I'm not sure about

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern, observers

I'm learning object oriented design patterns, but don't see why this is not the observer pattern if I only have concrete listener and subjects. In my practice example I have created a DMV office scenario with a single subject called the DmvCounter and Customers (the observers). In my main method, the customers are constructed with the task they would like the DMV office to complete for them.

```
Customer bob = new Customer("Bob", "Register Vehicle", 201); // number is bob's order
Customer pat = new Customer("Pat", "Renew License", 202);
dmvObject.register(bob);
dmvObject.register(pat);

dmvObject.handleRequest(200); // nothing happens - no customer for this request number
dmvObject.handleRequest(202); // prints: "Pat says: Thank you - Renewed License"
```

My question is the above is an interprocess communication between 2 objects only. No Interface for observer, and no interface for subject. Subject notifies it's list of concrete customers of a particular order number that has been completed.. And the customer leaves the DMV office satisfied. Is this not the observer pattern?

[image]

Comment: I Worked hard on this problem and question, I want to know WHY is this marked for close? Why are people telling me this is NOT the observer pattern?? That's why I asked this question..

Comment: What makes you think this isn't an example of an Observer pattern?

Comment: I've been told, the observer pattern needs to be abstract. There needs to be an observer interface rather than the concrete subject and concrete observer as I've shown here.

Comment: The whole point of the observer pattern is that observers can register for events. They implements the `Observer` interface, register for events and the observed object notifies the observers when an update occurs.

Comment: yes, but is it mandatory that there is an observer interface? So the subject contains a list of IObservers, rather than the concrete observers? I was told, not using the interface is not the observer pattern

Comment: I would agree that this is not an example of the observer pattern. First, there is the question whether the observer has to be abstract. One could argue for that, demanding that the logic of the observer and the observable have to be decoupled by leaving it entirely open what the observer does when notified - not sure (and convinced) of that, though. More importantly: in your example, you merely dispatch the job to the customers, whereas the observer pattern usually involves a *state change* of the observable object (to which observers react).

Comment: I would think that it is mandatory that the observed object knows how to notify the observers. It's normally done using an interface but as long as the observed object knows how to call the `notify` method, I don't think that it matters too much.

Comment: I think that if you're asking this question because the question was asked during an exam, interview or for some homework then your interviewer might have been looking for a more formal version of the pattern and in that case, your implementation would not have met the requirements

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the Observer pattern.

In a typical Observer implementation, the subject maintains a list of dependents and notifies those dependents by calling a method on each of them. That's the situation you have described.

Now, you could make the argument that this isn't a particularly useful implementation of the Observer pattern, because the Observable object needs to not only know what type of object is observing it, but needs to know the method signature of the observing object. This isn't particularly extensible because `DmvCounter` can't be observed by anything other than a `Customer`.

The benefit of implementing an interface (like `java.util.Observer`) is that you can add any variety of observers without needing to change `DmvCounter`, and all can be notified using a single method `update(Observable o, Object arg)`.

Comment: yea, but they are referring to an interface. There is an observer interface. I've been told without the interface this is not actually the observer pattern..

Comment: That's a standard implementation detail, but not a mandatory part of the pattern. It often makes sense to have the concrete class implement an interface so that you can decouple the implementation of the observer from the notifying method, and have a standard `notify` method. You could make the argument that your example isn't a particularly extensible/reusable implementation, but it still meets the general requirements for an Observer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of design pattern sticks with the idea of OOP, therefore every design pattern must contain as many concepts of OOP as possible. You have to understand the concept of OOP before moving to design pattern, otherwise it would be quite confused.

So why we need interface? The answer is for polymorphism.

Imagin that you have another customer, say customer2. Then in your DmvCounter, you have to implement all the functions for customer2 like this:

```
public class DmvCounter() {
    List<Customer> customer = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    List<Customer2> customer2 = new ArrayList<Customer2>();

    public void register(Customer customer) {
        //do something
    }

    public void register(Customer2 customer2) {
        //do something
    }
```

Now imagine you have 100 type of customers, and with each type you do exactly the same job for register. If you have to implement the register code 100 times, it would be an extremely time-consuming and painful task. So the idea of polymorphism is: whatever type of consumer is, it is still a consumer, and you just need 1 register function for that.

So to answer your question, yes it is still a kind of observe pattern. But it is not an observe pattern, because it doesn't meet the requirement of OOP, which is polymorphism